# How can I translate my flexible search query properly for a Java Final String query?

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud, flexible-search

I'm trying to make a webservice on Hybris Commerce to return data from models. My query works for flexible search console, but I have syntax problems with my method in Java.

My flexible search query:

```
select * from {address as a join customerenvasado as c on {a:owner} = {c:pk}} where {c:rut} like '1754%'
```

My error:

```
{"errors": [{
    "message": "type code 'a: owner' invalid",
    "type": "FlexibleSearchError"
}]}
```

My function:

```
public AddressModel getCustomerEnvasadoForRut(String rut) {
    validateParameterNotNull(rut, "Rut must not be null!");
    final String querys = "SELECT * FROM {a: " + AddressModel._TYPECODE + " as a join " + CustomerEnvasadoModel._TYPECODE + " as c on {a:owner} = {c:pk}} where {c:rut} like ?ParamRut";

    final FlexibleSearchQuery query = new FlexibleSearchQuery(querys);
    query.addQueryParameter("ParamRut", rut);
    List<AddressModel> result = getFlexibleSearchService().<AddressModel>search(querys).getResult();
    if (result != null && !result.isEmpty()) {
        return result.get(0);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your query as follows and it should work:

```
SELECT {pk} FROM {Address AS a JOIN customerenvasado AS c ON {a:owner} = {c:pk}} WHERE {c:rut} LIKE '1754%'
```

In place of the query given above, you can also use the following query:

```
SELECT {pk} FROM {Address AS a}, {customerenvasado AS c} WHERE {a:owner} = {c:pk} AND {c:rut} LIKE '1754%'
```

Comment: It works! I was reading about this and I catch the problem. You answer its ok. To complement it: The querys in hybris return all the attribute values when you select the PK. My new query: 

  final String queryString = "SELECT "+CustomerEnvasadoModel.PK+" FROM " +
                "{"+CustomerEnvasadoModel._TYPECODE+" as c join "+AddressModel._TYPECODE+" as a on" +
                " {c:"+CustomerEnvasadoModel.DEFAULTSHIPMENTADDRESS+"}={a:"+AddressModel.PK+"}} .....

Answer (score 1):

Your error is here:

`"SELECT * FROM {a: " + AddressModel._TYPECODE`

Remove the "a:" and it will work.